# Help to flush a particular set of equations to the left margin

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

So I have this code

```
\begin{align}
{P_1} = {p_0}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
{P_2} = {p_0} + {\frac{rKT}{2}}{e^{ - {\frac{rT}{2}{rT}}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2)) - \frac{\delta S_0 T}{2}e^{-\frac{\delta T}{2}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2))
\end{align}

\begin{align}
{P_3} = &{p_0} + {\frac{rKT}{3}}\left[ { e^{ - {\frac{rT}{3}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2rT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))}\right] \nonumber\\
&- {\frac{{S_0}T}{3}}\left[ {     e^{ - {\frac{\delta T}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2aT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))} \right]
\end{align}
```

it produces the following (with showframe) [image]

SADLY, I want p1  to be flushed to the left side aswell

Comment: `align` is specifically for having several equations in one block and aligning them. You can put all equations in one environment and align them with `&`.

Comment: you should never have a blank line before a display or consecutive `align` or `align` with only one row and no `&` alignment points

Answer (score 2):

with use `multlined` from `mathtools` (and after clean-up clutter in your equations):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P_{1}   & = p_{0}                                                               \\
P_{2}   & = p_{0} + \frac{rKT}{2}\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{rT}{2}{rT}}
                N\bigl(- d_{-}(S_{0},B_{\frac{T}{2}},T/2)\bigr) 
                - \frac{\delta S_{0}T}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\delta T}{2}}
                 N\bigl(- d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{T}{2}}T/2)\bigr)                           \\
P_{3} & =  \begin{multlined}[t]
    p_{0} + \frac{rKT}{3}\Bigl[\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{rT}{3}}
        N\bigl(-d_{-}(S_{0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)\bigr)     
        + \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2rT}{3}} 
            N(-d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))\Bigr]        \\[1ex]
        - \frac{{S_0}T}{3}\Bigl[\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\delta T}{3}}
        N\bigl(-d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{ T}{3}},T/3)\bigr)
        + \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{2aT}{3}}
        N\bigl(- d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3)\bigr) \Bigr]
            \end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

or with use of `split`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P_{1}   & = p_{0}                                                               \\
P_{2}   & = p_{0} + \frac{rKT}{2}\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{rT}{2}{rT}}
                N\bigl(- d_{-}(S_{0},B_{\frac{T}{2}},T/2)\bigr)
                - \frac{\delta S_{0}T}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\delta T}{2}}
                 N\bigl(- d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{T}{2}}T/2)\bigr)                           \\
    \begin{split}
P_{3} & =  p_{0} + \frac{rKT}{3}\Bigl[\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{rT}{3}}
        N\bigl(-d_{-}(S_{0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)\bigr)
        + \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2rT}{3}}
            N(-d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))\Bigr]        \\[1ex]
      &\qquad
       - \frac{{S_0}T}{3}\Bigl[\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\delta T}{3}}
        N\bigl(-d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{ T}{3}},T/3)\bigr)
        + \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{2aT}{3}}
        N\bigl(- d_{+}(S_{0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3)\bigr) \Bigr]
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

if you like to have all equation left aligned (to some indent) than use option `fleqn` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `flalign` environment provided by `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
P_{1}&=p_{0}\\
P_{2}&=p_{0} + {\frac{rKT}{2}}{e^{ - {\frac{rT}{2}{rT}}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2))- \frac{\delta S_0 T}{2}e^{-\frac{\delta T}{2}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2))\\
P_{3}&={p_0} + {\frac{rKT}{3}}\left[ { e^{ - {\frac{rT}{3}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2rT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))}\right] \nonumber\\
&- {\frac{{S_0}T}{3}}\left[ {     e^{ - {\frac{\delta T}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2aT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))} \right]
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the problem is that it would make all my equations flush left and I don't want that. I just want p1 to flush left.

Comment: @asdf wasn't that what you were after? You clearly state it in your question!

Comment: i was not clear maybe, but this is just a part of a paper I'm writing sorry for the confusion

Comment: @asdf  I actually do not understand what you're after

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flalign` as in, but you should avoid such long (unbroken) formulas. Maybe you should also consider using only one `flalign` environment with linebreaks and correct alignment.

[image: flalign]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
{P_1} &= {p_0}\\
{P_2} &= {p_0} + {\frac{rKT}{2}}{e^{ - {\frac{rT}{2}{rT}}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2)) - \frac{\delta S_0 T}{2}e^{-\frac{\delta T}{2}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2))\\
{P_3} &= {p_0} + {\frac{rKT}{3}}\left[ { e^{ - {\frac{rT}{3}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2rT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))}\right] \nonumber\\
&- {\frac{{S_0}T}{3}}\left[ {     e^{ - {\frac{\delta T}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2aT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))} \right]
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `alignat` and split the first equation at the `-` sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
{P_1} &= {p_0} && \\
{P_2} &= {p_0} &&+ {\frac{rKT}{2}}{e^{-{\frac{rT}{2}{rT}}}}N(-{d_-}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2))\notag\\
      &        &&- \frac{\delta S_0 T}{2}e^{-\frac{\delta T}{2}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},{B_{{\frac{T}{2}}}},T/2))\\
{P_3} &= {p_0} &&+ {\frac{rKT}{3}}\left[ { e^{ - {\frac{rT}{3}}}N( - {d_-}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2rT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))}\right] \nonumber\\
      &        &&- {\frac{{S_0}T}{3}}\left[ {     e^{ - {\frac{\delta T}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{T}{3}},T/3)) + e^{ - {\frac{2aT}{3}}}N( - {d_+}({S_0},B_{\frac{2T}{3}},2T/3))} \right]
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]